# How to write a user-defined command in vim?

Tags: user-commands

I have read `map.txt` in vim doc and tried to create my Ex command. But the doc is quite hard to understand.

I wanna write a command to call 2 command is `PlugInstall` and `CocInstall`.

```
command! MyCommand :PlugInstall<Cr>:CocInstall<Cr>
```

But it didn't work. Any different document to help me write user-defined command easier? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `:command` like `:map`
to map a series of keys. But they are different. In a user-defined
command, you don't need `:` to enter into command-line mode
and you don't need `<CR>` to execute the command and you need to
use `|` to separate the commands. You can try using the following:

```
command! MyCommand PlugInstall | CocInstall
```

You can refer to [:help 40.2](https://vimhelp.org/usr_40.txt.html#40.2) in the user-manual for information
about creating new commands.

Comment: Can you give me another reference for this ( videos, maybe)? I've tried to understand official doc but it's quite hard for newbie like me.